# android ListView equivalence in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

hi guys want to create a page(or pages) that changes based on a particular users info (as in name ,picture, number) and I know that in android you can use ListView for that. What is the equivalence of that in flutter or what can I use to do that in flutter

Comment: have you checked https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/?

Comment: yh, buh couldn't really make anything out

Answer (score 2):

If you are an Android developer you should take a look at this [page](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/) 
so

> The equivalent to a ListView in Flutter is … a ListView!
>
> In an Android ListView, you create an adapter that you can then pass
>   into the ListView which will render each row with what your adapter
>   returns. However you have to make sure you recycle your rows ,
>   otherwise, you get all sorts of crazy visual glitches and memory
>   issues.
>
> In Flutter, due to Flutters immutable widget pattern, you pass in a
>   List of Widgets to your ListView and Flutter will take care of making
>   sure they are scrolling fast and smooth

- [ListView Sample Apps](https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/ListView_index/)